# what is the difference between PhysicsSprite and CCSprite?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, physics, ccsprite

I am new to Cocos2D and I've realized that most of the codes written before the Cocos2d update used CCSprites. Recently I realized a lot of more recent codes after the update are using PhysicsSprite. What is the difference? what cases will one be perferred over the other? or What advantages does one have over the other, if any?

Comment: This was cross-posted [to GameDev.SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28974/). I flagged this to be closed, but on second hand it might belong here - I am not sure. In any case, please do not cross-post questions between Stack Exchange sites - it decreases the usefulness of them.

Answer (score 5):

PhysicsSprite is a CCSprite which uses a physics body to control the sprite's motion (position) and rotation.

Depending on whether you start with the Box2D or Chipmunk template, PhysicsSprite will either have a b2Body (Box2D) or a cpBody/cpShape (Chipmunk) as instance variables.

If you're not planning to use physics, use CCSprite. If you do, use PhysicsSprite for those sprites which represent physics objects.